# Coding program to calculate any chosen discounts with Output

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am on the final of a very introductory Computer Science class and it has some Visual Basic 2012 programming. One of our assignments before said final is to create a Auto Insurance Calculator that basically computes using a base insurance payment ($2400.00) and then up to 7 discounts with varying percentages and then Payment type "Monthly, Quarterly, Semi, Annual" and then the program outputs the total payment amount including the discounts into a label

This is my code below. and I have it to Calculate it correctly but I have to put in a defined percentage since I have a total of a 17% discount I put ".17" but I wish whatever discounts are chosen in the check boxes  to be outputted into total

If you need more information let me know. This seems rather difficult for a beginning programming class and we only went up to Chapter 6 in the Visual Basic 2012 book.

My GUI Mockup

GUI mockup screenshot here http://puu.sh/oMn3K/7590cc2def.jpg

Controls Used -  Groupbox at left: Checkboxes,
               Groupbox at right: Radio Buttons,
               3 Buttons at the bottom,
               **Label at bottom: Output**

```
Public Class frminsurance
    Private Sub btncalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalculate.Click
        Dim snginscost As Single = 2400.0

        ' Monthly Payment 
        If radmonthly.Checked Then
            snginscost = (snginscost - (snginscost * 0.17) / 1)
        End If


        ' Quarterly Payment 
        If radquarterly.Checked Then
            snginscost = (snginscost - (snginscost * 0.17) / 3)
        End If

        ' Semi-annual Payment
        If radsemi.Checked Then
            snginscost = (snginscost - (snginscost * 0.17) / 6)
        End If

        ' Annual Payment 
        If radannually.Checked Then
            snginscost = (snginscost - (snginscost * 0.17) / 12)
        End If

        lbltotal.Text = snginscost.ToString("C")
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdclear.Click
        radmonthly.Checked = False
        radquarterly.Checked = False
        radsemi.Checked = False
        radannually.Checked = False

        Chk25.Checked = False
        Chkgood.Checked = False
        Chkhonor.Checked = False
        Chkmarried.Checked = False
        Chknonsmoker.Checked = False
        Chkparents.Checked = False
        Chktactical.Checked = False

        lbltotal.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdexit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdexit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can use a switch case statement to find the percentage value based on checkbox selection.

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't complain about `cmdclear_Click` not working, I can *safely* assume that all those `Chk25`, `Chkgood`, etc. references works properly

so you could try adding this code in `btncalculate_Click` right after `Dim snginscost As Single = 2400.0` statement :

```
Dim percentage As Double

Select Case True
    Case Chknonsmoker.Checked
         percentage=0.04
    Case Chkgood.Checked
         percentage=0.05
    Case Chktactical.Checked
         percentage=0.05
    Case Else
         percentage=0.03
End Select
```

I hope that my attempt at ***helping*** you will not hurt you as jitendra garg did...

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code to get the percentage value.

```
Dim percentage As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim chkbx As CheckBoxList

chkbx = CType(FormView1.FindControl("CheckBoxList1"), CheckBoxList)
For i = 0 To chkbx.Items.Count - 1
  If chkbx.Items(i).Selected Then
    percentage = chkbx.Items(i).Value  
  End If
Next
```

Then replace all `0.17` with `percentage` and it will work.

If the number of checkboxes are same, you can hard code everything like below:

```
If Chk25.Checked Then
percentage = 0.03
Else If Chkgood.Checked Then
percentage = 0.05
End If
```

P.S. It is actually a good problem for starters, not that difficult to be honest. Just try to learn breaking problems into smaller problems. Divide and conquer, always remember that. :)

Edit: Can we stop with this `negative votes without mentioning the reason` thing? Is this reddit/4chan?

Comment: You are so awesome! thank you I will get this in and see how it goes

Figured it had to be something declared

Comment: Forgot to mention: Will this work even if  those checkboxes are in a group box?

Comment: Added it. The FormView1 is blue lined stating it is not declared I looked for this control in the toolbox and it's not there. I don't know who -1 your answer :/

Comment: `FormView1` is the name of form. You might have different form name. I think `frminsurance` is the form name in your case.

Comment: Changed `FormView1` to `frminsurance` and its now saying "FindControl is not a member of WindowsAppilcation1.frminsurance. I've added a screenshot of my GUI and below the list of controls I used.

Comment: Then what is the name you used for the form? I assumed it is same as class name which you put `frminsurance`. Check the properties of the form and see what is the name there? Also, if not, use the second method.

Comment: Under the "Design" Category (Name) property  is `frminsurance`

Comment: Weird. I have no idea what I am missing there. BTW, try the second method. Hopefully that will work.